# ZipWithLatestForm *Wanted Operator* or Workaround

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs6

**Lets consider following streams:**

```
Stream1: 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9                
Stream2: abc  d       fg   h
```

**Output I would like to get with combining these streams:**

```
[1, a]
[2, b]
[3, c]
[4, d]
[5, d]
[6, f]
[7, g]
[8, h]
[9, h]
```

**Sample Code Idea:** [StackBlitz Editor Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-zip-with-latest-form)

```
const input$ = fromEvent(document, 'keydown')
  .pipe(
    map((event: KeyboardEvent) => event.keyCode)
  );
const source$ = interval(500).pipe(s$ => zip(s$, input$))
source$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

So this is something like operators `zip()` and/or `withLatestForm()`, but I can't come up with solution

- *Main idea is that I have interval of 500ms and on every tick I want to zip it with Keyboard Input Observable, which works how I would like, but as long I am not emitting Keyboard Input Observable everything stops. **I want to keep emitting interval ticks, but if keyboard events stop then take the latest value***

Comment: Does the output at the beginning of your question actually represent your use case? I'm not at all sure that it does. In which case, there are two questions within your question.

Comment: I guess I didn't give the best description. Yes it does actually represent my case. Whenever keyboard inputs are incoming faster than interval ticks I want them to be somewhat saved in memory so that when later ticks arrive they are matched together, but whenever there are no more keyboard inputs I want latest keyboard input to be matched with the tick

Comment: Please have look at streams again, I edited them to better demonstrate my use case

Comment: I presume that you would like to have a interval to keep going and taking the latest value from what you have type (keyboard event). 
Please see below is the fork from your Stackblitz and I modified that to try to answer your question.

Comment: My post was deleted by moderator due to lack of information and not solving problems. However, if you are still interested - [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-zip-with-latest-form-terxdq?file=index.ts) is the link.
The modification is minimal, the operator you need is `combineLatest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time of thinking on the solution I came up with solution like so, [StackBlitz Edit Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-zip-with-latest-form-solution):

```
const interval$ = interval(500).pipe(share());
const input$ = fromEvent(document, 'keydown')
  .pipe(
    map((event: KeyboardEvent) => event.keyCode),
    concatMap(key => interval$.pipe(map(tick => key), take(1))),
  );

const source$ = interval$.pipe(withLatestFrom(input$))
source$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

**I delayed input$ with the help of interval$ and concatMap (notice take(1) as well).**

ConcatMap helped me to prolong input$ events and wait for interval event to fire its own event. Using withLatestForm helped me to match ticks with their own input$ values.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use withLatestFrom

```
import { of, fromEvent, interval } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, withLatestFrom } from 'rxjs/operators';

const input$ = fromEvent(document, 'keydown').pipe( map((event: KeyboardEvent) => event.keyCode));
const timer$ = interval(1000);
const source$ = timer$.pipe(withLatestFrom(input$));

source$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Try out this live demo at stackblitz -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-bmx7hg

As soon as you focus the page and press some key, the stream will start and you will get an emitted value on every tick, no matter if you clicked a button since the last tick.

Comment: Please have look at streams again, I edited them to better demonstrate my use case. As for my use case please consider that I would like to have more like zip functionality, because using `withLatestFrom()` will emit whenever any of the (source1 or source2) observables emit. And I would get many more emitted items at final subscription than I would like

Comment: No, by using withLatestFrom, it will only emit if the source stream (in my example timer$) emits. You can also check this in my demo - just press keyboard buttons furiously - there will ever only be one emitted value every second

Comment: Yes I agree with you but using `withLatesForm()` will give me [1, a] and [2, c]. [2,b] would be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know rxjs well enough to say whether there's a builtin that already does this, but you should be able to handle it with an explicit queue:

```
import { of, fromEvent, interval } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, withLatestFrom } from 'rxjs/operators';

const queue = [];
const input$ = fromEvent(document, 'keydown').pipe(map((event: KeyboardEvent) => {
    queue.push(event.keyCode);
    return queue;
});
const timer$ = interval(1000);
const source$ = timer$.pipe(withLatestFrom(input$), map(([tick, queue]) => {
    if (queue.length > 1)
        return queue.shift();
    else
        return queue[0];
}));

source$.subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Thanks I guess that would be working since my case is exactly queue functionality. I wanted some kind of rxjs operator